# How to eager load deeper twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

in my Post model i try to eager load user (the owner of post), favorite, and comments with authors of each comment :

```
 Post.all.includes(:user, :original => {:favorite, :comments => :author })
```

but it doesn't work , i get error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...(:user, :original => [{:favorite, :comments => :author}... ...
```

can someone tell me where is the problem  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, it's just a syntax error.  You've used `{:favorite, :comments => :author}` which is not a valid Hash.

Use an array as the value for `:original` to do what you want:

```
Post.includes(:user, :original => [:favorite, :comments => :author]).all
```

Your confusion might stem from the omission of some curly braces for Hashes which are not required in all cases. Re-writing the above with the curly braces explicitly added might make it more clear:

```
Post.includes(:user, {:original => [:favorite, {:comments => :author}]}).all
```